# Get Previous Months in python-Django

Tags: python, django

I want to generate a code in python to get the previous 10 months from the month we are in and the next month (to get some stats for it and labels in Line chartJs)
e.g(we are currently in December 2019 , I want it to show from Feb 2019 - Jan2020)

I have tried the old way but it is fixed range:

```
        months =[]
        for j in range(12):
            curr_month = calendar.month_name[j]
            my = [curr_month,y]
            months.append(my)
        # print(months)
        lnqs_rfq =[]
        lnqs_local =[]
        allrq = []
        for i in range(12):
            lnqs_rfq.append(Request.objects.filter(req_date__month=(i),req_type='stock').count())
            lnqs_local.append(Request.objects.filter(req_date__month(i),req_type='Local').count())
            allrq.append(Request.objects.filter(req_date__month=(i)).count())
```

I tried also panda but I don't get the previous months :

```
td = datetime.today()
mon = pd.date_range(start=td ,periods = 12, freq='MS').strftime("%b,%Y").tolist()
print(mon)
```

I hope you help me if there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick clarification, you want a ```list``` of ***Month*** and ***Year*** as ```String```? So that you can use it as labels for your chart correct?

Comment: yes , that's right

Comment: Great, will post my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `python-dateutil` to achieve this.

Make sure you install it using

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from collections import deque

today = datetime.now()
# Get next month and year using relativedelta
next_month = today + relativedelta(months=+1)
# How many months do you want to go back?
num_months_back = 10

i = 0
deque_months = deque()

while i <= num_months_back:
    curr_date = today + relativedelta(months=-i)
    deque_months.appendleft(curr_date.strftime('%B %Y'))

    if i == num_months_back:
        deque_months.append(next_month.strftime('%B %Y'))

    i = i+1

# Convert deque to list
print(list(deque_months))
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ... but when I pass it to the chart it gives me (TypeError: Object of type deque is not JSON serializable).. Any thoughts? thank you again

Comment: What are you using to pass JSON to your template? ```JsonResponse```? Post your ```views.py``` so that I can see and help you out with the error.

Comment: Any progress? @GHS

Comment: No I'm using django APIview (django rest framework) and passing the response ..I will post it now sure

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date

names = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')

def get_date(months): # months - difference in months
    year = date.today().year
    month = date.today().month + months
    if month <= 0:
        year += int(month / 12 - 1)
        month = month % -12 + 12
    elif month > 12:
        year += int((month - 1) / 12)
        month = month % 12
    return '{} {}'.format(names[month - 1], year)

print(get_date(-10), get_date(1), sep=' - ')
```

**Output**

Feb 2019 - Jan 2020

---

*If you'd prefer to use a library, you could make use of python-dateutil's **relativedelta***

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

names = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')

def get_date(months):
    rel_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=months)
    return '{} {}'.format(names[rel_date.month - 1], rel_date.year)

print(get_date(-10), get_date(1), sep=' - ')
```

**Output**

Feb 2019 - Jan 2020

---

**And to prove that they act identically**

```
for i in range(-10000, 10000):
    if get_date(i) != get_date2(i):
        raise Exception('Diversity detected')

print('perfect match')
```

**Output**

perfect match

Answer (score 0):

View.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from collections import deque

class ChartData(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        td = datetime.today()
        m =td.month
        y = td.year

        #######LINE Cahrt #######


        today = datetime.now()
        # Get next month and year using relativedelta
        next_month = today + relativedelta(months=+1)
        # How many months do you want to go back?
        num_months_back = 10

        i = 0
        deque_months = deque()

        while i <= num_months_back:
            curr_date = today + relativedelta(months=-i)
            deque_months.appendleft(curr_date.strftime('%B %Y'))

            if i == num_months_back:
                deque_months.append(next_month.strftime('%B %Y'))

            i = i+1

        # Convert deque to list
        print(list(deque_months))


        lnqs_rfq =[]
        lnqs_local =[]
        allrq = []
        for i in range(12):

        lnqs_rfq.append(Request.objects.filter(req_date__month(i),req_type='stock').count())
        lnqs_local.append(Request.objects.filter(req_date__month(i),req_type='Local').count())
        allrq.append(Request.objects.filter(req_date__month=(i)).count())

        total = allrq
        lnrfq_data = lnqs_rfq
        lnlocal_data = lnqs_local

        data ={
            'months':months,
            'lnrfq_data': lnrfq_data,
            'lnlocal_data':lnlocal_data,
            'total':total
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: @Paolo can you please check this

Comment: Have you tried, ```data = { 'months' : list(deque_months), 'lnrfq_data': lnrfq_data,
            'lnlocal_data':lnlocal_data,
            'total':total
        }```?